# How i can Start an Activity For Result and get the result from the activity that i started?

Tags: android, android-layout

can any body explain me How i can Start an Activity  For Result and get the result from the activity that i started?
Thanks and Regards
RizN81

Comment: Please Check official document its a very basic question .

Comment: It a very basic question with a lot of answers around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let you want to call ActivityB from ActivityA
Follow the following steps

**Step-1** in activityB set the result

**in ActivityB** set the result using `setResult()` see the sample code for ActivityB

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("hh", hour);
            intent.putExtra("mm", min);
            intent.putExtra("ss", sec);
            intent.putExtra("am", am);
            setResult(2, intent);
```

**step-2** call activityB from ActivityA
**in ActivityA** call activityB from activityA using following code

```
startActivityForResult(activityBIntent,1);
```

**step-3** write the logic you want to perfom after getting result from activityB in activityA

when ActivityB finished control will come to `onActivityResult()` method of calling acticity (ActivityA)

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (resultCode == 2) {
                int hour = data.getIntExtra("hh", 0);
                int min = data.getIntExtra("mm", 0);
                int sec = data.getIntExtra("ss", 0);
                int am = data.getIntExtra("am", 0);

            }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use this
in the activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_IMAGE ); //SELECT_IMAGE is an static int value.
```

this code for result

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         switch(requestCode) {
         case SELECT_IMAGE:
                 ///// write code here for your requirement
         }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your activity start with startActivityForResult() method and onActivityResult() method check if your activity got completed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

IN Activity_A

```
// Activity Callback Variable
private static final int FROM_ACTIVITY_B = 2;

// Now Start the Activity B from Activity A
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class), FROM_ACTIVITY_B);
```

IN Activity_B

```
// Now Place the following code when you want to pass the result to caller Activity which in our case is Activity_A
Intent data = new Intent();
// Put some data in the intent if you want those in the Activity_A
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
Activity_B.this.finish();
```

IN Activity_A

Now to get the result in Activity_A you need to override onActivityResult in Activity_A

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == FROM_ACTIVITY_B) {
            // Intent data is the one you passed from the Activity_B
            // Do whatever you want here...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks can i send the String data to Activity A from B?

Comment: Sure, put a string value in the Intent data and retrieve it in onActivityResult ..